# Изменение стиля определенных значений в таблице

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Есть большая таблица. Нужно стилизовать ячейки только с отрицательными значениями. Как? Четные, нечетные и т.п. можно через :nth-child. Как их отобрать по отрицательному значению?

Comment: Что значит "по отрицательному значению"?

Comment: По-моему без js никак..

Comment: Ну то есть есть положительные и отрицательные числа. Ну типа 1,2832,  35,81 и  -289,87, -6,525 ))

Comment: Ну а как в JS сделать?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если есть возможность использовать jQuery то можно примерно так:

```
$('td').each(function () {
  var item = $(this);
  var value = parseInt($.trim(item.text()));

  if (value < 0) {
    item.addClass('below');
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3a1kabgk/1/

Но если будет много элементов то работать будет уже не очень.

Comment: только 4 ячейки окрасилось)

Comment: @iorg А можно пример вашей таблицы?

Comment: Спасибо, но уже не стоит, ибо сделал вручную) Ну если только в познавательных целях могу скинуть часть таблицы. Только вот куда, не знаю)